# Why am I getting "'ResultSet' has no attribute 'findAll'" using BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, urllib2, beautifulsoup

So I am learning Python slowly, and am trying to make a simple function that will draw data from the high scores page of an online game. This is someone else's code that i rewrote into one function (which might be the problem), but I am getting this error. Here is the code:

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> def create(el):
    source = urlopen(el).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
    get_table = soup.find('table', {'id':'mini_player'})
    get_rows = get_table.findAll('tr')
    text = ''.join(get_rows.findAll(text=True))
    data = text.strip()
    return data

>>> create('http://hiscore.runescape.com/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=bigdrizzle13')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    create('http://hiscore.runescape.com/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=bigdrizzle13')
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 6, in create
    text = ''.join(get_rows.findAll(text=True))
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For what it's worth: naming your variables "first", "second", etc. is terrible style. You really should be more descriptive - the specific names are up to you, of course, but I might use "urlcontent", "parser", "mp_tables", and so on.

Comment: Its my third day with Python. I need to do that to keep it straight in my head. That will get better as time goes on...

Comment: I changed variable names. Hope thats better.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Wow. Triptych provided a [*great* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989872/how-do-i-draw-out-specific-data-from-an-opened-url-in-python-using-urllib2/989920#989920) to a related question.

We can see, [from BeautifulSoup's source code](http://code.google.com/p/google-blog-converters-appengine/source/browse/trunk/lib/BeautifulSoup.py), that `ResultSet` subclasses [`list`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

In your example, `get_rows` is an instance of BS's `ResultSet` class,  
and since BS's `ResultSet` subclasses `list`, that means **get_rows is a list**.

`get_rows`, as an instance of `ResultSet`, does **not** have a `findAll` method implemented; hence your error.  
What Triptych has done differently is to **iterate** over that list.  
Triptych's method works because the items in the `get_rows` list are instances of BS's Tag class; which has a `findAll` method.

So, to fix your code, you could replace the last three lines of your `create` method with something like this:

```
for row in get_rows:
    text = ''.join(row.findAll(text=True))
    data = text.strip()
    print data
```

Note to Leonard Richardson:  in no way do I intend to demean the quality of your work by referring to it as BS ;-)

Comment: `text=True` was just what I was looking for!