# How do I find all rows in one table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write my first parser with BeautifulSoup (BS4) and hitting a conceptual issue, I think. I haven't done much with Python -- I'm much better at PHP.

I can get BeautifulSoup to find the table I want, but when I try to step into the table and find all the rows, I get some variation on:

```
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'attr'
```

I tried walking through the sample code at [How do I draw out specific data from an opened url in Python using urllib2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989872/how-do-i-draw-out-specific-data-from-an-opened-url-in-python-using-urllib2/989920#989920) and got more or less the same error (note: if you want to try it you'll need a [working URL](http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore/compare.ws?user1=Jake).)

Some of what I'm reading says that the issue is that the ResultSet is a list. How would I know that?  If I do `print type(table)` it just tells me `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>`

I can find text in the table with:

```
for row in table:
    text = ''.join(row.findAll(text=True))
    print text
```

but if I try to search for HTML with:

```
for row in table:
    text = ''.join(row.find_all('tr'))
    print text
```

It complains about `expected string, Tag found` So how do I wrangle this string (which is a string full of HTML) back into a beautifulsoup object that I can parse?

Comment: Can you show your complete code and the actual traceback error you get?

Comment: your `''.join()` is the issue.  `row.find_all('tr'))` returns a group of tags, not strings--  a BeautifulSoup object.  `type(row.find_all('tr'))`.  Just because it prints like a string, doesn't make it one.

Comment: Actually ... it looks like all I needed was `for row in table.find_all('tr'):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BeautifulSoup data-types are bizarre to say the least. A lot of times they don't give enough information to easily piece together the puzzle. I know your pain! Anyway...on to my answer...

Its hard to provide a completely accurate example without seeing more of your code, or knowing the actual site you're attempting to scrape, but I'll do my best.

The problem is your `''.join()`. `.findAll('tr')` returns a list of elements of the BeautifulSoup datatype 'tag'. Its how BS knows to find `tr`s. Because of this, you're passing the wrong datatype to your `''.join()`.

You should code one more iteration. (I'm assuming there are `td` tags withing the `tr`s)

```
text_list = []
for row in table:
    table_row = row('tr')
    for table_data in table_row:
        td = table_data('td')
        for td_contents in td:
            content = td_contents.contents[0]
            text_list.append(content)
text = ' '.join(str(x) for x in text_list)
```

This returns the entire table content into a single string. You can refine the value of `text` by simply changing the locations of `text_list` and `text =`.

This probably looks like more code than is required, and that might be true, but I've found my scrapes to be much more thorough and accurate when I go about it this way.

Comment: This is helpful, tho as it turns out all I needed was `for row in table.find_all('tr'):`